# fgets in C language multiple prints after get string

Tags: c, loops, printf, fgets

I have that code and I want my loop finish when user gives "###".

```
int main(){

   char s[10];

    printf("Give string: ");
    fgets(s,11,stdin);
    do{
        printf("Give string: ");
        fgets(s,11,stdin);
    }while ( s!="###" );
    return 0;
}
```

So far it's ok, but when the user gives an input bigger than 11 characters I have multiple prints of "Give String".
I try it with `scanf` and I did it right. Can anyone give me a solution to do it with `fgets`?
[I mean the output looks like this.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/v3TzB.png)

Comment: Two points: you cannot compare a C string with `s!="###"`, and, `fgets` includes any trailing `newline`, in the string, so even `strcmp` will not work.

Comment: BTW, you declare `char s[10];` so at most nine characters and the terminating null byte, but you call `fgets` with *11* ; and a fix-my-code question is off-topic!

Comment: Also, don't read 11 characters into a 10 character array.

Comment: I suspect a `while` loop is better than `do-while`  since you ignored the first input.

Comment: So, compile with all warnings & debug info (e.g. `gcc -Wall -g`), improve your code till you get no warnings, and **use the debugger** (`gdb`)

Comment: Please don't show an image for simple output from a progam.  Copy'n'paste the output into the question body, and then select it and use the **`{}`** button above the edit box to indent the output as 'code'.  If you're feeling fancy, you can prefix it with `<!-- language: lang-none -->` on an unindented line before the output; that stops SO highlighting the output, but is definitely a refinement.

Comment: You should be using a top-checked loop `while (fgets(s, sizeof(s), stdin) != 0)` (or `NULL` instead of `0`) so that the program stops on EOF.  Yours doesn't stop on EOF.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

C string doesn't support direct comparison, you would need `strcmp` for that, so

`while ( s!="###" )` should be `while(strcmp(s,"###"))`

Also you'd need to remove `\n` from `fgets` (so as `strcmp` to ignore `\n`). So the `do..while` should look like:

```
do{
    printf("Give string: ");
    fgets(s,11,stdin);
    s[strlen(s) - 1] = '\0'; 
} while (strcmp(s,"###"));
```